# Pivot XAML Control - Changing the Style (Border)

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

[image]

## Pivot Control Black Box

The goal is to change the color of the **black border** around my Pivot control.

**I created a copy of the template for the pivot control** so I can modify the style. It isn't obvious how to modify the style to change the color of the this black brush.

**Added Border Brush -** I looked at BorderBrush but it doesn't really feel like change?

**Where and how** - to best achieve the changing of a border color? The red dotted boxes are not changing the color.

[image: Corresponding XAML]

Answer (score 1):

The black border in your picture is actually the auxiliary border after the focus switch. Setting its color cannot be done by `BorderBrush`.

Please find the `ContentControl` named **HeaderClipper** in Pivot's default style template and add the following properties:

```xml
<ContentControl x:Name="HeaderClipper"
                FocusVisualPrimaryBrush="{TemplateBinding FocusVisualPrimaryBrush}"
                ...>
    <!-- other code -->
</ContentControl/>
```

Then set the `FocusVisualPrimaryBrush` property on the `Pivot` control to the color you need:

```xml
<Pivot FocusVisualPrimaryBrush="White">
    <!-- other code -->
</Pivot>
```

If you want to learn more about `Focus`, you can refer to this document: [Reveal Focus](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/style/reveal-focus#customize-the-margin)

Comment: Yes, I thought I wrote a note yesterday but I don't see it. Thank you!!. One final question is border thickness - do I have to modify the FocusVisualPrimaryBrush?

Comment: Hi, if you want to modify the border thickness, you need to change the `FocusVisualPrimaryThickness`, and if you want to change the border color, yes, you need to modify the `FocusVisualPrimaryBrush`

Comment: Nice! Straightforward. I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: I used this and discovered that I also had to set the FocusVisualSecondaryBrush in order to get rid of a small, thin white outline.